# code duplication

Tags: django, code-duplication

Here is the layout:
[image]
Here is the code:

```
#base.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="l_col">
                {% block left %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div id="r_col">
                {% block right %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
#views.py
def list( request ):
    vars = RequestContext( request, {
        'news': News.objects.all(),
        'top_news': News.news_manager.get_top_news()
    } )
    return render_to_response( 'news/list.html', vars )

def view( request, id ):
    vars = RequestContext( request, {
        'news': News.objects.filter( id = id ),
        'top_news': News.news_manager.get_top_news()
    } )
    return render_to_response( 'news/view.html', vars )
#news/list.html and news/view.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block left %}
    <!-- loop for news -->
{% endblock %}
{% block right %}
    <!-- loop for top news -->
{% endblock %}
```

As you see variable 'top_news' repeats in methods: 'list', 'view' and in 2 templates same loop for top news 
How to eliminate this duplication of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a template_tag, that would handle the top_news. Than you won't have to pass them in the views, but include it everywhere you need it in the templates.

[Inclusion Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) might be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Custom template tag for top news.